# How to select a polygon in QGis grahical modeler using a parameter as input

Tags: parameters, qgis

I would like to select a single polygon from a shape using a value present in a field `COMUNE` so I need to have the list of values as the parameter for the input

In the image, I would like to have the possibility to choose the name of "Comune" from a list:

[image]

I don't know how it's possible to have a parameter list from values present in a specific field. I solved the problem by writing the name directly in the algorithm, but I would like to choose from a list.

Comment: It is highly suggested to ask QGIS-related questions on [the Geographic Information Systems SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)